# How to log in with another user than the current windows user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I created a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project that uses Windows authentication. The goal here is to create an intranet application that everyone within the network can use after logging in with their own AD account.

On my development machine I'm running IIS Express from Visual studio, and I created a local group called 'Test'. We also have an AD server with a group called Test, which resides in the domain COMPANY. I gave everyone in the COMPANY\Test group access to the local Test group. Then I added two users to the COMPANY\Test group on the AD server: myself and my colleague.

When I launch the website (which is protected with `[Authorize(Roles = "Test")]`, I am prompted for a username/password. This works for my own credentials, which are the same as the Windows account I'm currently logged in with. But when I try to log in with my colleague's credentials, I'm getting an error that the user is unauthorized. What I want is the ability to log in with another AD account on my machine, without having to log out of windows and signing in with a different user. Is that possible, or is that just not how Windows Authentication works?

The error message I get is: 401.3 you don't have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied.

Comment: Probably the other user is not in the role `Test`.

Comment: @Ben yes, both users are in the Test group on the AD server. I also ran `net user <user> /Domain` to confirm this.

Comment: The test Role is not the test Group. Roles are not groups.

Comment: @Ben according to https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs a role matches a Windows local group (which is also called Test). And we both are in this group.

Comment: What's the exact error message? It will contain a code such as 401.2 or similar.

Comment: @Ben the error is: 401.3 you don't have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied

Comment: What's the ACL on the directory? Does that include Test also? (I assume you are impersonating)

Comment: @Ben thank you! I managed to fix it by giving the Test local group access to the solution folder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it thanks to Ben from the comments. What was missing was that my local group didn't have permission to access my solution folder on the file system. By giving the Test group access to the solution folder I managed to log in with different accounts.